# Better way to perform logic in one line

Tags: objective-c, ternary-operator, boolean-logic

Is there a better way to perform this logic in one line?

```
- (BOOL)isValueInRange {
    return ((level.integerValue > 100) || (level.integerValue < 0)) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
return level.integerValue >= 0 && level.integerValue <= 100;
```

This will return true if the value is in the range, false if it is not.

Comment: Super. I didn't think about inverting the conditions to avoid the `!` sign. Good stuff!

Comment: @pnizzle Given the name of the method, this form of the check is far more readable than the original code with its inverse check.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can escape having to repeat `level.integerValue` twice.

```
return !((level.integerValue > 100) || (level.integerValue < 0))
```

You can also use `NSLocationInRange`:

```
NSLocationInRange(level.integerValue, NSMakeRange(0, 100)
```